# pass parameters to batch file via File URI in Windows

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, command-line-arguments, parameters

Using Windows 10 here.

Code in `open_video.bat`

```
"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\VLCPortable media player\VLCPortable.exe" --start-time=54 --stop-time=89 "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\some_video.mkv"
```

Location of `open_video.bat` is `C:`

in Notepad++ I have this link below and I call the batch file by double-clicking on it:

```
file:///C:\open_video.bat
```

When I double-click the batch file, it opens `some_video.mkv` in VLC starting at the `54` second mark, plays it up to the `89` second mark, and then loops the video between those two timestamps.

However, I don't want to hard code `54` and `89`. Is there any way I can write the link to the batch file, and modify the code in the batch file such that I can pass `54` or whatever and `89` or whatever as a parameter or argument?

E.g., re-write the link to the batch file to something like:

```
file:///C:\open_video.bat?start=54&end=89
```

and modify the batch file's code like so:

```
"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\VLCPortable media player\VLCPortable.exe" --start-time=start --stop-time=end "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\some_video.mkv"
```

or some such?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the batch file like this:

```
"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\VLCPortable media player\VLCPortable.exe" --start-time=%1 --stop-time=%2 "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\some_video.mkv"
```

Then call it like:

```
C:\open_video.bat 54 89
```

Or in file URI:

```
file:///C:\open_video.bat%2054%2089
```

In encoded URL %20 is space and replace 54 and 89 with parameters.

Comment: You got exactly what I was trying to do. Kudos for that. I really want this solution to work via file URI. And had even tried it earlier but it didn't work. I'm sure it works via the command line, but when I encode the file URI the way you've shown it, nothing happens when I double click the URI. I think Windows is unable to read that I'm trying to open a batch file, and doesn't bother to run it. Upvoted for trying to help.

Comment: @thanks_in_advanced is there any specific reason you want to use File URI?

Comment: Am trying to create links in Markdown (app is Joplin) such that I can play short pieces from a large, long, locally stored video. Currently, I'm creating a separate batch file for each clip I want to play (with `start` and `end` points). I was thinking that maybe I can have a single batch file, and pass it the `start` and `end` parameters when writing the link in Markdown. That way I won't need a large number of batch files. But it's looking to me like there may not be such a way possible, so am resigned to simply create a large number of batch files.

Answer (score 1):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141333/9731176, this does not appear to be possible in most contexts:

> I am assuming you are using Windows? If so, there is no way to pass a parameter using the "file://" syntax, as it is an Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol that does not accept parameters.